# Building complex query for many tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have six tables:

```
Keys( id, name )
Values( id, name )
PropertyRoles( id, name )
Properties( id, name, key_id, value_id, role_id )
Components( id, name, type )
ComponentProperties( id, component_id, property_id, proprole_id )
```

As an input I have a list of key-value pairs. I want to find all components which have at least one property related to key-value pair from input list with role name = X. At end I want to collect all data about founded components(`id,name,properties`).

Can someone help me with building appropiate query for this?
EDIT: I have completly no idea where to start

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, p.name FROM components c 
INNER JOIN componentproperties cp ON cp.role = ( SELECT id FROM propertyroles WHERE name = 'primary' ) AND cp.component_id = c.id
INNER JOIN properties p ON p.key_id = ( SELECT id FROM keys WHERE name IN ( %1 ) ) AND  p.value_id = ( SELECT id FROM values WHERE name IN ( %2 ) )
UNION ALL
SELECT cp2.name FROM componentproperties cp2 WHERE cp2.id IN cp.id
UNION ALL
SELECT keys.name FROM keys WHERE keys.id IN %1
UNION ALL
SELECT values.name FROM values WHERE values.id IN %2
ORDER BY c.name;
```

PS. Sorry for my english!

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, depending on what version of Postgresql you have. I solve it here with multiple sub queries.

**NOTE**: In you `Properties`-table you specify the role of the property, but you also have that in `ComponentProperties`. I assume that you don't want to have the same data in more than one place, so in the solution here I assume that the role_id of `ComponentProperties` don't exists.

**The first problem** to solve is how to get your list of key:value-pairs into the query so they can be searched for.

One way is to create a (temporary) table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE key_value_role AS (
  key text,
  value text,
  role text
);
```

And then insert all the values in that table.

```
INSERT INTO key_value_role VALUES
('Key 1', 'Value 1', 'Role 1'),
('Key 2', 'Value 2', 'Role 1'),
('Key 2', 'Value 3', 'Role 1');
```

Even with a temporary table it quickly gets messy. Fortunately `VALUES` can be used stand-alone:

```
SELECT column1 as key, column2 as value, column3 as role
FROM (
  VALUES
    ('Key 1', 'Value 1', 'Role 1'),
    ('Key 2', 'Value 2', 'Role 1'),
    ('Key 2', 'Value 3', 'Role 1')
) AS kvr
```

If you are using Postgresql >= 9.3 you can send the data as string of serialized JSON, and iterate over the keys with [json_each_text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT *, 'Role 1'::text as role
FROM json_each_text('{"Key 1":"Value 1", "Key 2":"Value 2"}')
```

In the example above the I use a literal string, but I assume you will use a parameterized query and compose the JSON-serialization-string in your program.

The limitation with the above method is that a specified key only can have one value. Maybe that is enough, but I wanted a flexible solution to be able to search for more than one value of each key.

There is another function in Postgresql >= 9.3 that can be used [json_populate_recordset](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html), but it requires a base type. The base type could be an existing table, but you can also create a type to be used:

```
CREATE TYPE key_value_role as(
  key text,
  value text,
  role text
);
```

When the type is specified, `json_populate_recordset`can be used:

```
SELECT *
FROM json_populate_recordset(null::key_value_role,'[{"key":"Key 1", "value":"Value 1", "role":"Role 1"},{"key":"Key 2", "value":"Value 2", "role":"Role 1"}, {"key":"Key 2", "value":"Value 3", "role":"Role 1"}]')
```

Example output:

```
   key   |   value   |  role
--------+------------+----------
 "Key 1" | "Value 1" | "Role 1"
 "Key 2" | "Value 2" | "Role 1"
 "Key 2" | "Value 3" | "Role 1"
```

Now you can populate the object with multiple values for each key, and also search for different roles in the same query.

**Next problem** is to convert the names into ids. You didn't specify the type of your ids. I assumed integers.

Assume that the list created with a method above is called `list`, then the conversion from name to ids could be made like this:

```
SELECT
  Keys.id as key_id, Values.id as value_id, PropertyRoles.id as role_id,
  Keys.name as key_name, Values.name as value_name, PropertyRoles.name as role_name 
FROM list
  JOIN Keys ON ( list.key = Keys.name )
  JOIN Values ON ( list.value = Values.name )
  JOIN PropertyRoles ON (list.role = PropertyRoles.name )
```

Example output:

```
 key_id | value_id | role_id | key_name | value_name | role_name
--------+----------+---------+----------+------------+-----------
      1 |        1 |       1 | "Key 1"  | "Value 1"  | "Role 1"
      2 |        2 |       1 | "Key 2"  | "Value 2"  | "Role 1"
      2 |        3 |       1 | "Key 2"  | "Value 3"  | "Role 1"
```

With the table above, we can now join it with Properties:

```
SELECT Properties.id as property_id, Properties.name as property_name, kvr.*
FROM Properties
  JOIN (
    -- previous query here
  ) AS kvr ON ( Properties.key_id = kvr.key_id AND Properties.value_id = kvr.value_id AND Properties.role_id = kvr.role_id )
```

Example output:

```
 property_id |    property_name     | key_id | value_id | role_id | key_name | value_name | role_name
-------------+--------------------+--------+----------+---------+----------+------------+-----------
           1 | "Property 01 k1v1r1" |      1 |        1 |       1 | "Key 1"  | "Value 1"  | "Role 1"
          13 | "Property 13 k2v2r1" |      2 |        2 |       1 | "Key 2"  | "Value 2"  | "Role 1"
          16 | "Property 16 k2v3r1" |      2 |        3 |       1 | "Key 2"  | "Value 3"  | "Role 1"
```

And the table above can now be joined with ComponentProperties:

```
SELECT ComponentProperties.id as ComponentProperties_id, ComponentProperties.component_id, pkvr.*
FROM ComponentProperties
  JOIN (
    -- previous query here
  ) AS pkvr ON ( ComponentProperties.property_id = pkvr.property_id )
```

Example output:

```
  componentproperties_id | component_id | property_id |    property_name     | key_id | value_id | role_id | key_name | value_name | role_name
-----------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+--------+----------+---------+----------+------------+-----------
                       1 |            1 |           1 | "Property 01 k1v1r1" |      1 |        1 |       1 | "Key 1"  | "Value 1"  | "Role 1"
                       2 |            1 |          13 | "Property 13 k2v2r1" |      2 |        2 |       1 | "Key 2"  | "Value 2"  | "Role 1"
                       3 |            1 |          16 | "Property 16 k2v3r1" |      2 |        3 |       1 | "Key 2"  | "Value 3"  | "Role 1"
                       4 |            2 |           1 | "Property 01 k1v1r1" |      1 |        1 |       1 | "Key 1"  | "Value 1"  | "Role 1"
                       7 |            3 |          16 | "Property 16 k2v3r1" |      2 |        3 |       1 | "Key 2"  | "Value 3"  | "Role 1"
                       9 |            4 |          13 | "Property 13 k2v2r1" |      2 |        2 |       1 | "Key 2"  | "Value 2"  | "Role 1"
```

And finally, join it with Components:

```
SELECT Components.name as component_name, Components.type as component_type, cpkvr.*
FROM Components
  JOIN (
    -- previous query here
  ) AS cpkvr ON ( Components.id = cpkvr.component_id )
```

Example output:

```
 component_name |  component_type  | componentproperties_id | component_id | property_id |    property_name     | key_id | value_id | role_id | key_name | value_name | role_name
----------------+----------------+------------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+--------+----------+---------+----------+------------+-----------
 "Component 1"  | "Component type" |                      1 |            1 |           1 | "Property 01 k1v1r1" |      1 |        1 |       1 | "Key 1"  | "Value 1"  | "Role 1"
 "Component 1"  | "Component type" |                      2 |            1 |          13 | "Property 13 k2v2r1" |      2 |        2 |       1 | "Key 2"  | "Value 2"  | "Role 1"
 "Component 1"  | "Component type" |                      3 |            1 |          16 | "Property 16 k2v3r1" |      2 |        3 |       1 | "Key 2"  | "Value 3"  | "Role 1"
 "Component 2"  | "Component type" |                      4 |            2 |           1 | "Property 01 k1v1r1" |      1 |        1 |       1 | "Key 1"  | "Value 1"  | "Role 1"
 "Component 3"  | "Component type" |                      7 |            3 |          16 | "Property 16 k2v3r1" |      2 |        3 |       1 | "Key 2"  | "Value 3"  | "Role 1"
 "Component 4"  | "Component type" |                      9 |            4 |          13 | "Property 13 k2v2r1" |      2 |        2 |       1 | "Key 2"  | "Value 2"  | "Role 1"
```

---

**This is the whole query**, using json_populate_recordset:

```
-- Get components from matching properties
SELECT Components.name as component_name, Components.type as component_type, cpkvr.*
FROM Components
  JOIN (
    -- Get component id from matching properties
    SELECT ComponentProperties.id as ComponentProperties_id, ComponentProperties.component_id, pkvr.*
    FROM ComponentProperties
      JOIN (
        -- Get propety id and name of matching values
        SELECT Properties.id as property_id, Properties.name as property_name, kvr.*
        FROM Properties
          JOIN (
            -- Convert key, value and role names to id
            SELECT
              Keys.id as key_id, Values.id as value_id, PropertyRoles.id as role_id,
              Keys.name as key_name, Values.name as value_name, PropertyRoles.name as role_name 
            FROM
              json_populate_recordset(null::key_value_role,'[{"key":"Key 1", "value":"Value 1", "role":"Role 1"},{"key":"Key 2", "value":"Value 2", "role":"Role 1"}]')
              AS list
              JOIN Keys ON ( list.key = Keys.name )
              JOIN Values ON ( list.value = Values.name )
              JOIN PropertyRoles ON (list.role = PropertyRoles.name )
          ) AS kvr ON ( Properties.key_id = kvr.key_id AND Properties.value_id = kvr.value_id AND Properties.role_id = kvr.role_id )
      ) AS pkvr ON ( ComponentProperties.property_id = pkvr.property_id )
  ) AS cpkvr ON ( Components.id = cpkvr.component_id )
ORDER BY component_name, property_name
```

---

And here is the test data I used:

```
CREATE TYPE key_value_role as(
  key text,
  value text,
  role text
);

create table Keys(
  id integer unique primary key,
  name text unique
);

create table Values(
  id integer unique primary key,
  name text unique
);
create table PropertyRoles(
  id integer unique primary key,
  name text unique
);
create table Properties(
  id integer unique primary key,
  name text,
  key_id integer references Keys,
  value_id integer references Values,
  role_id integer references PropertyRoles
);
create table Components(
  id integer unique primary key,
  name text unique,
  type text
);
create table ComponentProperties(
  id integer unique primary key,
  component_id integer references Components,
  property_id integer references Properties,
  unique ( component_id, property_id )
);

INSERT INTO Keys values
(1, 'Key 1'),
(2, 'Key 2'),
(3, 'Key 3');

INSERT INTO Values values
(1, 'Value 1'),
(2, 'Value 2'),
(3, 'Value 3');

INSERT INTO PropertyRoles values
(1, 'Role 1'),
(2, 'Role 2'),
(3, 'Role 3');

INSERT INTO Properties values
( 1, 'Property 01 k1v1r1', 1, 1, 1),
( 2, 'Property 02 k1v1r2', 1, 1, 2),
( 3, 'Property 03 k1v1r3', 1, 1, 3),
( 4, 'Property 04 k1v2r1', 1, 2, 1),
( 5, 'Property 05 k1v2r2', 1, 2, 2),
( 6, 'Property 06 k1v2r3', 1, 2, 3),
( 7, 'Property 07 k1v3r1', 1, 3, 1),
( 8, 'Property 08 k1v3r2', 1, 3, 2),
( 9, 'Property 09 k1v3r3', 1, 3, 3),
(10, 'Property 10 k2v1r1', 2, 1, 1),
(11, 'Property 11 k2v1r2', 2, 1, 2),
(12, 'Property 12 k2v1r3', 2, 1, 3),
(13, 'Property 13 k2v2r1', 2, 2, 1),
(14, 'Property 14 k2v2r2', 2, 2, 2),
(15, 'Property 15 k2v2r3', 2, 2, 3),
(16, 'Property 16 k2v3r1', 2, 3, 1),
(17, 'Property 17 k2v3r2', 2, 3, 2),
(18, 'Property 18 k2v3r3', 2, 3, 3),
(19, 'Property 19 k3v1r1', 3, 1, 1),
(20, 'Property 20 k3v1r2', 3, 1, 2),
(21, 'Property 20 k3v1r3', 3, 1, 3),
(22, 'Property 20 k3v2r1', 3, 2, 1),
(23, 'Property 20 k3v2r2', 3, 2, 2),
(24, 'Property 20 k3v2r3', 3, 2, 3),
(25, 'Property 20 k3v3r1', 3, 3, 1),
(26, 'Property 20 k3v3r2', 3, 3, 2),
(27, 'Property 20 k3v3r3', 3, 3, 3);


INSERT INTO Components values
(1, 'Component 1', 'Component type'),
(2, 'Component 2', 'Component type'),
(3, 'Component 3', 'Component type'),
(4, 'Component 4', 'Component type');

INSERT INTO ComponentProperties values
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 3),
(3, 1, 5),
(4, 2, 1),
(5, 2, 5),
(6, 2, 6),
(7, 3, 1),
(8, 4, 5),
(9, 4, 6);
```

Comment: Uhh, this is a big thing! Many thanks for really detailed explanation. Long way ahead for me to fully understand this :)

Comment: It's not a beginner level kind of query, but when it is broken down in smaller pieces it should not be too hard to understand. You will learn. :) There is some "magic" with data formated as JSON that you might not have seen before. Let me know if there is something special that you don't understand about the query, and I will try to explain.

Comment: @geo-amateur By the way, when you ask a question like this, it is great if you provide commands to create tables and insert some test data, like I have in the last part of my answer. Feel free to copy relevant parts from my answer to your question if you decide to update your question.